# Filling overlapping paths

Tags: gimp, path

I have a text layer whose letter-spacing is set to a negative value, and thus letters overlap. This is my intention.

[image]

I transform the text layer to path and hide the original text as I don't need it anymore. The letters are made of separate closed curves whose areas overlap, mirroring their original respective positions properly.

[image]

However, if I will this path I'm getting holes where the characters are overlapping -- this is **not** what I want.

[image]

**How can I fill them in, in general?**

I've simplified the flow here, so it looks pointless to do *text to path* but I actually use the transform tool on the path before filling it in.

In this concrete example, a making a selection out of path and then removing holes would work, but now if there's a letter with a hole in it such as O or B, so that's out of question too, although it served me as quick workaround a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like GIMP 2.10.8 really has no automatic way to fill paths including their overlapping sections. I can think of two workarounds of which only one really seems to work:

## Workaround 1 – Selection To Path

Instead of using `Layer → Text to Path`, use `Layer → Transparency → Alpha to Selection` followed by `Select → To Path`. That way you end up with an overlap-free path that can be filled as expected.

[image: Workaround 1]

## Workaround 2 – Processing Paths In Another Program

If you cannot use the first Workaround because you need the letters to be separated you can post-process paths in another program, for instance Inkscape.

- Convert the text to a path
- Edit your path as you would normally
- When finished, right click the path and select `Copy Path` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> did not work for me).
- Open Inkscape
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (paste path), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> (union paths), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (copy path)
- Back in GIMP, paste the path with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Unfortunately, GIMP sometimes shifts parts of pasted paths as seen in the following picture. So far I haven't found a solution to this problem.

[image: Workaround 2]

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a little script to assist:

1. Get and install [ofn-path-edits](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/). And read the doc.
2. Use its `Break text path apart` function (not to be confused with its plain `Break text path apart` function). This should normally create one path per letter (you can get extra paths for diacritics but here it won't be a problem).
3. Delete the initial path, and make sure you have one single image open, and no selection in it.
4. Start the python console (`Filters>Python-fu>Console`) and enter:

   ```
   image=gimp.image_list()[0]
   ```

   then:

   ```
   for p in image.vectors: pdb.gimp_image_select_item(image, CHANNEL_OP_ADD,p)
   ```

[image]

Step 4 can be replaced by [ofn-paths-to-selection](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/).